# Android Wear WearableListenerService doesn't trigger on Android 8 Oreo when app closed

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, android-wear-2.0

I have a [`WearableListenerService`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService) on a phone app that receives a `DataItem` from the watch (in `onDataChanged`). The code is essentially the same you have on [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events#with-a-wearablelistenerservice) (I can put it here if useful).

When a new `DataItem` is received, I show a notification to the user on the phone.

It works for Android 5, regardless if the app is running or killed. It also works on Android O API 26 if the app is running/in memory, but it doesn't if I kill the app first (by swiping): the `WearableListenerService` does not run then.

I'm aware of the [background execution limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) on Android 8, but I don't how to deal with them in this case since it's Android that should start the service while my app is in background so that I can react to the Data Layer changes.

Is there a way to listen for Data Layer events on Android 8 while the app is in background?

Comment: "but it doesn't if I kill the app first (by swiping)" -- what device(s) are you testing on?

Comment: It happened with a **OnePlus 5T**. This device is very aggressive with background limits and doze mode. There is a screen in the Settings -> Battery -> Battery optimization in which you can relax the background "optimizations" for specific apps (you can see this screen [in this blog post](https://www.guidingtech.com/fix-oneplus-battery-optimization-reset-issue/), at the bottom, where it says "3. Disable Deep Optimization").

Comment: I don't have any Wear OS app experience, and I have not used `WearableListenerService` as a result. If you are in position to test on another device, it would be interesting to see if the problem is tied more specifically to devices with aggressive power management. For example, it is possible that "Disable Deep Optimization" does not cover this scenario, due to a bug or an intentional decision by the OnePlus developers.

Comment: Did u get any solution ?

Comment: @AkshayShah no sorry :( Maybe you could try to disable the battery optimization on the phone, but you can only do this on your phone, not for everyone.

Comment: Yes I implemented it by asking user not to optimize the app when the app starts. Though a bad solution but had to do it this way.